# One class classification with LIBSVM in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, svm, weka, libsvm

I have a dataset on a particular domain and I want to do a one-class classification with LIBSVM (wrapper) in Weka. I have trained the classifier, but the problem is, when I test it with a different dataset than the test set, I get all of them as correctly classified (which I know they are topically different from the training data so no way of correctly classifying). I experimented changing the gamma and the $\nu$ parameter but I can't make a reliable model.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would not use SVM's for one-class-classification problems (especially for text), due to their "magic parameters" that are only hard to be interpreted (e.g., the well-known [$C$ parameter problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31066/what-is-the-influence-of-c-in-svms-with-linear-kernel)).

There are other (much simpler) alternative methods that can also do the job, which can be implemented easily from scratch. Some of them are mentioned in the paper "[One-class document classification via Neural Networks](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S092523120600261X)", which i highly recommend to read.

There is also another paper that proposes an [authorship verification method](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1742287616000074) (an instance of one-class-classification problems) that deals with cross-topic texts. The learned model in this paper seems to be relieable enough to handle not only cross-topic but also cross-genre cases, even for different languages. Perhaps this could help...