# Over-fitting diagnosis method

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, overfitting, diagnosis

How much difference between train and test set errors can indicate over-fitting? For example in logistic regression.
I am trying to classify 11746 comments based on their sentiments in three classes using logistic regression. My train accuracy is about 100% but in test i get accuracy about 52%. I want to know how much difference between these factors can indicate over-fitting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> train accuracy is about 100% but in test i get accuracy about 52%

This is definitely overfitting. Usually we want the performance on training and testing almost the same. In addition, in most cases, we do not want training accuracy to be 100% since training data may contain noise and we want the model more "general" than training data.

My answer here gives a guidance to use learning curve for over-fitting diagnosis.

[How to know if a learning curve from SVM model suffers from bias or variance?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220827/how-to-know-if-a-learning-curve-from-svm-model-suffers-from-bias-or-variance)