# Is it possible to infer overfitting or underfitting from an accuracy vs epoch curve like the one below ? If yes, How?

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting

[image]

In this curve, there's a pretty big difference between validation and training accuracy in the end. Does that mean it's overfitting?

Comment: See also: [What exactly is overfitting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281449/what-exactly-is-overfitting)