# Is it correct to decrease the alpha parameter in sklearn SVM pipeline to improve performance?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn, natural-language

I'm trying to find the best parameters for a Fine-grained Sentiment Analysis of a dataset of movie reviews.

This is the current code:

```
class SVMSentiment(Base):
    """Predict sentiment scores using a linear Support Vector Machine (SVM).
    Uses a sklearn pipeline.
    """
    def __init__(self, model_file: str=None) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        # pip install sklearn
        from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer, TfidfVectorizer
        from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
        from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
        from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
        self.pipeline = Pipeline(
            [
 

                ('clf', SGDClassifier(
                    loss='hinge',
                    penalty='l2',
                    alpha=1e-4,
                    random_state=42,
                    max_iter=100,
                    learning_rate='optimal',
                    tol=None,

                )),
            ]
        )

    def predict(self, train_file: str, test_file: str, lower_case: bool) -> pd.DataFrame:
        "Train model using sklearn pipeline"
        train_df = self.read_data(train_file, lower_case)
        learner = self.pipeline.fit(train_df['text'], train_df['truth'])
        # Fit the learner to the test data
        test_df = self.read_data(test_file, lower_case)
        test_df['pred'] = learner.predict(test_df['text'])
        return test_df
```

If alpha = 1e-4, accuracy improves of about 0.5 percentage and I was wondering if that was correct and if so why, as I have seen online the default value is 1e-3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SGDClassifier, alpha is a parameter. It is the regularization parameter and even though there is a default value (1e-3 as you said) it is in fact not optimal at all in practice we should always change this default value and try other values of alpha using cross-validation to get a better score. **Be careful to use cross-validation or similar technique to validate that the change of parameter is indeed better than no changing.**

In short, this regularization parameter tries to find a balance between overfitting and underfitting and increasing this parameter will result in a classifier that is smoother, depending on the problem at hand, the task may be very hard to approximate with a smooth function or at the opposite you may need to smooth things up to avoid overfitting. For more information on the choice of alpha in particular, see [What exactly is overfitting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281449/what-exactly-is-overfitting). In general, the hyperparameters given as default in algorithms are not bad in a number of cases but you should always be careful that by changing from the default parameters, you could gain a lot of performance.

Comment: Thank you! So in this case, I read that SVM since it uses L2 regularization it has low risks of overfitting; since it is just a small increase (but still significant) should I still go with it without being worried?

Comment: To get any definite answer you need  to divide you dataset in a training dataset and validation dataset or use cross-validation, having L2 regulaization does not necessarily avoid overfitting, you can still overfit. I don"t know how you quantified the "accuracy improves 0.5 percent", if you did cross-validation or divided dataset then you don't have to worry, it should hold. If not, I would advise cross-validation as it is the easiest and most practical with scikit-learn with https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html

Comment: got it, thanks!!