# why does infinite-dimensional vector leads to poor generalization?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Ian Goodfellow in his book writes that When we use kernel trick to get an infinite-dimensional vector, we can always have enough capacity to ﬁt the training set, but generalization to the test set often remains poor. Why does the generalization remain poor?

Comment: Hi: there might be special details because it's a kernel but, simply speaking  it's due to over-fitting just like one can over-fit when building any model in machine learning-statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Goodfellow's example seems like a specific example of the bias-variance tradeoff. Fitting training data is pretty easy with modern machine learning methods; generalizing to unseen data is much harder. Striking the balance is where most of the work happens.

We have some threads about overfitting which might help.

- [What exactly is overfitting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/281449/what-exactly-is-overfitting)
- [Definition of Overfitting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304613/definition-of-overfitting)

Comment: Thanks @sycorax. This helps.