# Does SVM perform poorly with too few observations

Tags: machine-learning, svm, e1071

I try to train a linear SVM using package e1071, with cost=10 on the following data:

```r
    x <- matrix(c(-0.97, -0.69, -1.14, -0.93, 0.26, 1.14, 0.76, 
            1.32, -0.79, 1.04, -.80, -.97, -1.09, -1.09, 0.63, 
            1.09, 0.92, 1.49, -0.52, 0.34), 10, 2)
    colnames(x) <- c("X1","X2")
    y <- c(-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,-1)
    svm2 <- svm(x,y,type="C-classification", kernel="linear", 
                cost=10, scale=FALSE)
```

The data looks like:
[image]

In theory, point `E(0.26,0.63)` should also be a support vector. But `svm()` does not return it as a support vector, but considers point `T(1.14,1.09)` as SV. This happens also when I change the kernel to "radial".

In theory, E should be a support vector, while point T(1.14, 1.09) not, if I understand correctly the theory.

Might this inconsistency be due to the fact that I have only 10 observations?

Comment: How this is bad? You have one misclassified case.

Comment: I do not understand why E is not a support vector, given that it lies between the margins.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to apply the intuitions of a hard-margin SVM to the results of a soft-margin SVM and being led astray by the differences.

I can tell you're using a soft-margin SVM because you provided a "cost=10" parameter; the e1071 R library does not appear to support a hard-margin classifier directly, but you can approximate it by using a suitably huge cost parameter, say 1e10.

When the cost is low, [a soft-margin SVM will sometimes choose to misclassify one or more points if it means it can get a wider margin](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31066/what-is-the-influence-of-c-in-svms-with-linear-kernel). Perhaps surprisingly, they may do this even when the data are truly linear separable and a "perfect" solution could be found. If you increase the cost to 100 or 1,000 it will behave more like the hard-margin version and you will see it correctly classify all training examples.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that there exists a linear seperation of both classes without any loss. The correct support vectors should be S, T, A, D with a linear kernel. 
I do not see any inconsistency with E not beeing a support vector.

The plot illustrates the proper linear seperation of both classes (roughly, not done with svm), support vectors marked in red.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Can you please let me know what software and which package did you use to get your results?

Comment: I used Python (&matplotlib) to plot your data and I used my basic knowledge of SVM to identify the support vectors. Anyhow I would recommend to use Python and the Scikit-Learn package (well documented with a lot of further information). Although I do not use R, yet I never heard anything bad about it - so it seems to be just as fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think @olooney is correct, but IIRC (it is a long time since I read it) Vapnik's book makes a distinction between support vectors and *essential* support vectors.  Especially for linear classifiers in low dimensions, the optimal decision boundary can be defined using a subset of the support vectors.  SVM solvers don't necessarily give you *all* of the support vectors, just a set of support vectors that is sufficient to define the discriminant.  Not sure if that is the case here.

Try retraining the model with point E left out, if the outcome is the same, it is, at most, a non-essential support vector.  BTW I don't really understand the use of colours in the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `kernlab` in `R` to get the support vectors with linear kernel:

```
library(kernlab)
df <- as.data.frame(x)
df$y <- y
m <- ksvm(y~.,data=df,type="C-svc",
     kernel='vanilladot',C=10,prob.model=TRUE)
plot(m,data=df, xlim=c(-1.2,1.2), ylim=c(-1.2,1.2))
```

Note that the separating hyperplane found is different from the one drawn and the highlighted black points represent 4 support vectors. As expected, points near the decision surface are chosen to be the support vectors.

[image]

With RBF kernel (`rbfdot`) and keeping other hyper-parameters fixed, the decision surface becomes non-linear and SVM outputs more (7) support vectors, as shown below:

[image]

Changing (increasing) the regularization hyper-parameter $C$ (keeping other hyper-parameters fixed and using RBF kernel) will result in a different decision boundary and change (decrease) the number of support vectors (back to 4), as shown below.

[image]

The following animation shows how the decision surface (the orientation of the decision hyperplance along with the margins) and the support vectors change with different value of the hyper-parameter C and kernel. As expected, with soft-margin SVM (for low values of $C$), we need more support vectors, to allow more noisy data, when compared to hard-margin SVM, that requires less number of support vectors (with narrower margins).

[image]