# Does increasing C in epsilon-SVR increase the number of support vectors?

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, svm

As far as I understand the value of epsilon defines the data points (the support vectors) that get included in the computations. These are the points that lay outside of the 'tube' of width 2*epsilon.

[image: Fig.]'

On the other hand the C in the minimization problem seems to penalize the amount of deviations from the epsilon margin. Thus, does it define the number of support vector as well? Doasn't it decrease them?

[image: Fig.]

It contradict with what I experience while using sklearn.svm.SVR. I notice distinguish increase of computation time when I increase the value of C. Thus, it is contradicting with the above. Why increasing the constant C results in longer computation time?

*[the images are from "A tutorial on support vector regression" by ALEX J. SMOLA and BERNHARD SCHÖLKOPF](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B:STCO.0000035301.49549.88)

Comment: Check this answer (even though it uses classification example, the effect of C is same) - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31066/what-is-the-influence-of-c-in-svms-with-linear-kernel

Comment: Increasing $C$ means you place a higher priority on avoid mistakes. This actually doesn't necessarily mean you will have more support vectors. Generally speaking, when one looks at the optimization time one tends to look at $\lambda = \frac{1}{C}$ and how it impacts the strong convexity (i.e., increasing $C$ means we're still strongly convex, but with a "worse" constant) - this in turn does tend to mean that increasing $C$ results in longer optimization times.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What is lambda in your comment?