# Does increasing the value of C in svm.LinearSVC leads to overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning

I have made an svm.LinearSVC model to classify images. Firstly, the features of the images are extracted by SIFT and then based on them the LinearSVC is trained. I have the following Python snippet:

```
from sklearn import svm

model = svm.LinearSVC(C=2, max_iter=10000)

model(x_train, y_train.ravel())

y_pred = model(x_test)

print(metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

x_train shape is  (3700, 256) and x_test shape is  (1300, 256)
I have received the following accuracy results with the different values of **C**:

C = 2.0    => accuracy = 72.3%

C = 10.0   => accuracy = 82.9%

C = 100.0  => accuracy = 90.2%

C = 1000.0 => accuracy = 91.1%

C = 1500.0 => accuracy = 91.2%

Based on "Kent Munthe Caspersen" answer on [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31066/what-is-the-influence-of-c-in-svms-with-linear-kernel), in an SVM model, we look for a hyperplane with the largest minimum margin, and a hyperplane that correctly separates as many instances as possible.

Also I think C, as the regularisation parameter, prevents overfitting. So does the model explained above, suffers from overfitting and if so, then how do I find the appropriate value of C?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Now, turning to the question of overfitting, can you provide a definition of overfitting? How can you apply that definition to your observations here? Does that definition seem to fit? Why or why not?

Comment: @Sycorax Overfitting is when a model acquires the detail and noise from training data to the degree that the performance of the model has a negative effect on new data. And about applying this definition to this situation, I should add when I use the model to an unseen new data, the accuracy is very low like around 20%.

Comment: Sounds like you need to tune `C` to find a value that doesn't result in overfitting. We have lots of threads about this. https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=tune+c+%5Bsvm%5D

Comment: @Sycorax Thank you. I will look into them one by one, Hope to find the answer.